# What is wrong with my python program?

Tags: python

I'm learning to code in python using Project Euler. I've written the following program, which I think should work:

```
a=1
b=1
c=1

while(a<=998):
while(b<=998):
    c=(1000-(a+b)

    if (a*a+b*b==c*c):
        print a,b,c
    b=b+1
a=a+1
```

However, when I actually run the program from the terminal, the interpreter says that line 9

```
if (a*a+b*b==c*c):
```

is invalid. Can anyone tell me why this is?

thanks

Comment: Some questions should pass a basic compilation here before they get posted :D

Comment: you should not mix tabs with spaces, I recommend formatting your code for SO with spaces **only**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for Pythagorean triplets that satisfy a condition and you don't want triangles with negative sides:

```
for a in range(1, 999):
    for b in range(1, 1000 - a):
        c = 1000 - (a + b)
        if a * a + b * b == c * c:
            print a, b, c
```

And you can get the unique triplets in increasing order like this:

```
for a in range(1, 999):
    for b in range(a, 1000 - a):
        c = 1000 - (a + b)
        if a * a + b * b == c * c:
            print a, b, c
```

And there was a typo in your original code: `c=(1000-(a+b)`

Answer (score 4):

The immediately preceding line is missing a closing parenthesis:

```
    c=(1000-(a+b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel really dumb now. I'm sort of a newbie, and I wasn't thinking that an error the interpreter said was on one line could really be somewhere else.